# Common elements in two lists

Tags: java, arraylist, element

I have two `ArrayList` objects with three integers each. I want to find a way to return the common elements of the two lists. Has anybody an idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 195):

Use [`Collection#retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
listA.retainAll(listB);
// listA now contains only the elements which are also contained in listB.
```

If you want to avoid that changes are being affected in `listA`, then you need to create a new one.

```
List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<>(listA);
common.retainAll(listB);
// common now contains only the elements which are contained in listA and listB.
```

If you're a fan of streams, best what you could do is to [`Stream#filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) on [`Collection#contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) of the other list.

```
List<Integer> common = listA.stream().filter(listB::contains).toList();
// common now contains only the elements which are contained in listA and listB.
```

It's only at least twice slower.

Comment: RetainAll returns a new list?
I tried to store the output of retain to a new list sth like that
tempList.addAll(listA.retainAll(listB)); but it doesnt work

Comment: As answered in the link behind `Collection#retainAll()` and the comments in the code snippets, no, it doesn't. Changes get reflected in the list you're calling the method on.

Comment: The problem is that list common is initialized with size 3, then you try to change its size by returning only one or two elements. 
I try what you suggest and it returns me out of bounds exception.

Comment: In this approach, I will not be able to match occurrence number of element.......say for eg       listA {2,3,5} and listB {5 5} , if I will do listB.retainAll(listA) , listB will now have {5,5}......I want my final outcome after comparing listA and listB as {5}. Kindly suggest how we can achieve this

Comment: @NANCY The Commons Collections solution should work the way you wish, but not `retainAll()`

Comment: If done with poor choice of collection object, it could throw an UnsupportedOperationException.  The above example with ArrayList does work of course.

Answer (score 46):

You can use set intersection operations with your `ArrayList` objects.

Something like this:

```
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

l1.add(1);
l1.add(2);
l1.add(3);

List<Integer> l2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
l2.add(4);
l2.add(2);
l2.add(3);

System.out.println("l1 == "+l1);
System.out.println("l2 == "+l2);

List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(l2);
l3.retainAll(l1);

    System.out.println("l3 == "+l3);
```

Now, `l3` should have only common elements between `l1` and `l2`.

```
CONSOLE OUTPUT
l1 == [1, 2, 3]
l2 == [4, 2, 3]
l3 == [2, 3]
```

Comment: Note that this way the changes are reflected in `l2` as well. You probably meant to say `List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(l2);` instead.

Comment: The problem gets a little messier if say l1 has 2 of an element and l2 had 3 of that same element.  retainAll returns puts 3 of that element in l3 even though it is only contained twice in l1.

Answer (score 44):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html):

```
CollectionUtils.intersection(java.util.Collection a, java.util.Collection b)
```

Comment: This is a great solution, however as I mentioned above, it has different behavior than `retainAll()` on repeated elements.  So likely one is correct and one is incorrect depending upon how you approach the problem.

Answer (score 26):

Using Java 8's [`Stream.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method in combination with [`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

/* ... */

List<Integer> list1 = asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> list2 = asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
    
List<Integer> common = list1.stream().filter(list2::contains).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Contains looks like it'd be an O(n) operation, which would be called n times, unless the compiler does something clever. Does anyone know whether the above runs in linear or quadratic time?

Comment: It would be a n*n operation !

Comment: Note to reader: In Java 16+, replace [`.collect( Collectors.toList() )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) with shorter [`.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) (a new method on `Stream`).

Answer (score 6):

consider two list L1 ans L2

Using Java8 we can easily find it out

`L1.stream().filter(L2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
List<String> lista =new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> listb =new ArrayList<String>();

lista.add("Isabella");
lista.add("Angelina");
lista.add("Pille");
lista.add("Hazem");

listb.add("Isabella");
listb.add("Angelina");
listb.add("Bianca");

// Create an aplusb list which will contain both list (list1 and list2) in which common element will occur twice 
List<String> listapluslistb =new ArrayList<String>(lista);    
listapluslistb.addAll(listb);
                
// Create an aunionb set which will contain both list (list1 and list2) in which common element will occur once
Set<String> listaunionlistb =new HashSet<String>(lista);
listaunionlistb.addAll(listb);
                
for(String s:listaunionlistb)
{
    listapluslistb.remove(s);
}
System.out.println(listapluslistb);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the common elements between two lists using the method 
"retainAll". This method will remove all unmatched elements from the list to
which it applies.

```
Ex.: list.retainAll(list1);
```

In this case from the list, all the elements which are not in list1 will be 
removed and only those will be remaining which are common between list and 
list1.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(10);
list.add(13);
list.add(12);
list.add(11);

List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(10);
list1.add(113);
list1.add(112);
list1.add(111);
//before retainAll
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(list1);
//applying retainAll on list
list.retainAll(list1);
//After retainAll
System.out.println("list::"+list);
System.out.println("list1::"+list1);
```

Output:

```
[10, 13, 12, 11]
[10, 113, 112, 111]
list::[10]
list1::[10, 113, 112, 111]
```

NOTE: After retainAll applied on the list, the list contains common element between 
list and list1.

Comment: is intersection the method where we delete all the commons and keep the unique in the list from list 1?

Answer (score 4):

```
public <T> List<T> getIntersectOfCollections(Collection<T> first, Collection<T> second) {
        return first.stream()
                .filter(second::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Create two collections:
    LinkedList<String> listA =  new LinkedList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listB =  new ArrayList<String>();

    // Add some elements to listA:
    listA.add("A");
    listA.add("B");
    listA.add("C");
    listA.add("D");

    // Add some elements to listB:
    listB.add("A");
    listB.add("B");
    listB.add("C");

    // use 

    List<String> common = new ArrayList<String>(listA);
    // use common.retainAll

    common.retainAll(listB);

    System.out.println("The common collection is : " + common);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do it yourself..

```
List<Integer> commons = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (Integer igr : group1) {
    if (group2.contains(igr)) {
        commons.add(igr);
    }
}

System.out.println("Common elements are :: -");
for (Integer igr : commons) {
    System.out.println(" "+igr);
}
```

Comment: The OP was asking for a way to find which elements were common, not how many common elements there are.

Comment: @BrendonDugan - That is what this code does. The list `commons` contains the common elements. The second for-loop prints them on the console. I do not see where the code is counting the common elements.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia - When I made my comment (in 2013) the code only returned a count of common elements.

Comment: @BrendonDugan Oh, OK. Sorry about that. I should keep in mind that the answer can be edited in place but comments are usually left as is, in chronological order :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers above are similar but not the same so posting it as a new answer.

Solution:
1. Use HashSet to hold elements which need to be removed
2. Add all elements of list1 to HashSet
3. iterate list2 and remove elements from a HashSet which are present in list2 ==> which are present in both list1 and list2
4. Now iterate over HashSet and remove elements from list1(since we have added all elements of list1 to set), finally, list1 has all common elements
Note: We can add all elements of list2 and in a 3rd iteration, we should remove elements from list2.

Time complexity: O(n)
Space Complexity: O(n)

Code:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(4);
    list1.add(5);

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(1);
    list2.add(3);
    list2.add(5);
    list2.add(7);
    Set<Integer> toBeRemoveFromList1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
    System.out.println("list1:" + list1);
    System.out.println("list2:" + list2);
    for (Integer n : list2) {
        if (toBeRemoveFromList1.contains(n)) {
            toBeRemoveFromList1.remove(n);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("toBeRemoveFromList1:" + toBeRemoveFromList1);
    for (Integer n : toBeRemoveFromList1) {
        list1.remove(n);
    }
    System.out.println("list1:" + list1);
    System.out.println("collectionUtils:" + CollectionUtils.intersection(list1, list2));
    Assert.check(CollectionUtils.intersection(list1, list2).containsAll(list1));
```

output:

> ```
> list1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> list2:[1, 3, 5, 7]
> toBeRemoveFromList1:[2, 4]
> list1:[1, 3, 5]
> collectionUtils:[1, 3, 5]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> List<T> getCommonElements(
            java.util.Collection<T> a,
            java.util.Collection<T> b
            ) {
        if(a==null && b==null) return new ArrayList<>();
        if(a!=null && a.size()==0) return new ArrayList<>(b);           
        if(b!=null && b.size()==0) return new ArrayList<>(a);
        
        Set<T> set= a instanceof HashSet?(HashSet<T>)a:new HashSet<>(a);
        return b.stream().filter(set::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

For better time performance, please use HashSet (O(1) look up) instead of List(O(n) look ups)

Time complexity- *O(b)*
Space Complexity- *O(a)*

Answer (score 0):

Below code
Remove common elements in the list

```
List<String> result =  list1.stream().filter(item-> !list2.contains(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Retrieve common elements

```
List<String> result = list1.stream()
                .distinct()
                .filter(list::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what would be the complexity of this? is it efficient?

Answer (score 0):

The question talks about three items and many of the suggestions suggest using retainAll. I think it must be stated that as the size of the lists grown retainAll seems to become more inefficient.

In my tests I found that converting to Sets and looping is around 60 times faster than using retainAll for Lists with 1000s of items

```
  List<Integer> common(List<Integer> biggerList, List<Integer> smallerList) {
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(biggerList);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(smallerList.size());
    for (Integer i : smallerList) {
      if (set1.contains(i)) {
        result.add(i);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 below solution

```
list1.stream()
    .filter(list2::contains)
    .collect(Collectors
    .toList()));
```