# how to get common elements from string arraylist

Tags: java

i have 3 string list called Cname,cnamedb,Pname. These 3 lists has a result obtained by query the SQL database.cname and Pname results are getting from querying excel database. cnamedb  result is getting from querying SQL database.

i declared and stored into array like this.

```
 List Cname = new  ArrayList();
 List Pname =new ArrayList();
 List cnamedb=new  ArrayList();

  Cname.add(rs.getString("Cname"));
  Pname.add(rs.getString("Pname"));
  cnamedb.add(res.getString("Cname"));
```

i tried like this

```
        boolean hasCommonName = Cname.retainAll(Cnamedb);
         if(hasCommonName){
          out.println(Cname+"<br>");
         out.println(hasCommonName);
      }
       boolean haspname=Pname.retainAll(Cnamedb);
      if(haspname){
     out.println(haspname);
     }
```

This is just giving me a answer true for the first if statement but not printing the list elements. for the second if statements no results am getting.

i need to find out common elements exists in database and the excel, first i need to get common elements from Cname and Cnamedb and then from Pname and Cnamedb. how do i get the common elements.please provide me the code snippet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Common elements in two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists)  Also, it would be a lot easier to do the intersection in SQL instead of java.

Comment: please check the code which i have edited. even though using retainAll am not able to print the values.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

the below given snippet worked for me.

```
    List<String> commonToCnameAndCnamedb = new ArrayList<String>(Cname);

    List<String> commonToPnameAndCnamedb = new ArrayList<String>(Pname);

    boolean hasCommonName = commonToCnameAndCnamedb.retainAll(cnamedb);
    if (hasCommonName) {
        System.out.println(commonToCnameAndCnamedb + "<br>");
        System.out.println(hasCommonName);
    }
    boolean haspname = commonToPnameAndCnamedb.retainAll(cnamedb);
    if (haspname) {
        System.out.println(commonToPnameAndCnamedb + "<br>");
        System.out.println(haspname);
    }
```

Comment: its giving me true true for both if conditions. but its not printing the common elements System.out.println(commonToPnameAndCnamedb + "<br>");

Comment: I am also getting true for all the cases. But the common elements are listed properly for me. no idea what is happening there at your end