# Find common elements among N lists of byte arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, guava

I have a  declaration as `List<List<byte[]>>`, i.e. inner list is list of byte arrays and there are N such lists. I want to identify common byte arrays across all the lists. How would I do that? There is a discussion  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183982/is-there-a-way-to-find-common-elements-in-multiple-lists), but I donot know if it works for byte arrays

Comment: Why don't you check first it's working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the solution you've linked, but as arrays don't have `hashCode` overriden, you have to wrap them in `ByteBuffer`, using `ByteBuffer.wrap`. To extract the array from a `ByteBuffer`, call `array` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `equals(byte[] a, byte[] a2)`, as suggested [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).