# Is there a way to find common elements in grouped lists in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

```
 List<empl> lstSource = new List<empl>();

        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 2, Id = 101, Name = "S1" }); 
        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 2, Id = 109, Name = "S9" });
        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 2, Id = 102, Name = "S2" });
        

        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 4, Id = 101, Name = "S1" });
        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 4, Id = 102, Name = "S2" });
        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 4, Id = 108, Name = "S8" });

        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 3, Id = 105, Name = "S5" });
        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 3, Id = 103, Name = "S3" });
        lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 3, Id = 102, Name = "S2" });
```

should result {Id = 102, Name = "S2"}
if I add

```
lstSource.Add(new empl { departmentId = 3, Id = 101, Name = "S1" });
```

should result {Id = 102, Name = "S2"} {Id = 101, Name = "S1"}

Hint : we can group with departmentId and find common Id in 3 group.

Comment: What if there are multiple common elements? How are you determining a group? What makes an item a "common" one with another?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck trying this? Showing your own effort would probably make the question more clear.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck trying this? - I want to fetch list which is common in all group or in can say intersection of grouped (departmentId) items.

Comment: or refer close question -  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183982/is-there-a-way-to-find-common-elements-in-multiple-lists

Comment: What keeps yo from showing your own effort? The other question is completely different.

Comment: as i said it is very close to my question, difference is only i have complex type class (emp class) shared link having array of primitive data type. output is same like find common items in all sets/group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var groups = lstSource.GroupBy(t1=> t1.departmentId)
                     .ToList();
        var validIds = groups.First().Select(t1 => t1.Id).ToList();
        foreach (var g in groups.Skip(0))
        {
            var otherGroupItemIds = g.Select(t1 => t1.Id).ToList();
            validIds = validIds.Intersect(otherGroupItemIds).ToList();
           
        }
if (validSRIds.Count > 0)
                return lstSource.FindAll(t1 => validSRIds.Contains(t1.Id)).GroupBy(t2 => new { t2.Id, t2.Name }).Select(g => g.First()).OrderByDescending(t => t.Name).ToList();
```

you will get all common id,name which belongs to all group

Comment: yes both code is working

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments and example above, I take it that the `Name` associated with any given `Id` is always the same. In that case, you could split the `Id`s registered on each department into separate lists, then intersect those lists to find the common `Id`s, and then find the associated `Name` for each common `Id`.

You have done something similar in your own example. By rewriting the code (e.g. by replacing the `foreach` loop with an `Aggregate()` function) you could achieve a more straight forward approach:

```
var idsPerDepartment = lstSource
    .GroupBy(item => item.departmentId)
    .Select(gr => gr.Select(item => item.Id));

var commonIds = idsPerDepartment
    .Aggregate((common, next) => common.Intersect(next));

var commonItems = commonIds
    .Select(id => lstSource.First(item => item.Id == id))
    .Select(commonItem => new { commonItem.Id, commonItem.Name })
    .OrderByDescending(commonItem => commonItem.Name);
```

`commonItems` is empty (not `null`) if there are no common items.

It could all be written as one single expression, but I've spilt it into several variables to clarify what is happening along the way.