# check if three arrays have the same value

Tags: java

I put numbers of three people in one arraylist and in the case if three people have the same number then overall `occurrences++`; this is my algorithm but it is not working for this case!!

> 5 (first person has 5 nums)
>   13 20 22 43 146
>
> 4 (second person has 4 nums)
>   13 22 43 146
>
> 5 (third person has 5 nums)
>   13 43 67 89 146

```
int occurrences = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
    for (int j = n; j<n+b; ++j ){
        if(arr.get(i)==arr.get(j)){
            System.out.println(arr.get(i)+" " +arr.get(j));
            for(int k=n+b; k<arr.size(); ++k){
                if(arr.get(j)==arr.get(k)){
                    ++occurrences;
                    System.out.println(arr.get(k));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of data in the ArrayList? Strings? Integers? Longs?

Comment: of course integer, cause i am dealing with numbers

Comment: Too bad. If they were Strings, I know which question that would be duplicate of. Anyway, don't compare them with ==. Use equals.

Comment: You'd better to supplement n and b's value

Comment: I wish you'd share with us such mysteries such as what `b` is exactly. Or what is it you want, exactly.

Comment: i want to know how many numbers are repeated for three of them!!!n=5; b =4

Comment: still confused with what u really want ....there is a list of integers and you want how many number are repeated in a list is that what u want?????

Comment: Can a person have numbers repeated? Ex. first person has 2 13's?

Comment: If you want to compare two lists for common values see below URL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists

Comment: Yes Tejas Patel it is possible

Answer (score 1):

try this if you have 3 array of 3 person

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for 1st person seprated by ',' like 1,2,3....");
    String noForFirst = sc.nextLine();
    String[] a = noForFirst.split(",");
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for 2nd person seprated by ',' like 1,2,3....");
    String noForSecond = sc.nextLine();
    String[] b = noForSecond.split(",");
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for 3rd person seprated by ',' like 1,2,3....");
    String noForThird = sc.nextLine();
    String[] c = noForThird.split(",");
    int occurrences = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; ++j) {
            if (a[i].equals(b[j])) {
                for (int k = 0; k < c.length; ++k) {
                    if (a[i].equals(c[k])) {
                        ++occurrences;
                        System.out.println(a[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("occurrences = " + occurrences);
```

**Input**

`Enter numbers for 1st person seprated by ',' like 1,2,3....
1,5,9,7,6
Enter numbers for 2nd person seprated by ',' like 1,2,3....
1,4,8,7,3,5
Enter numbers for 3rd person seprated by ',' like 1,2,3....
1,7,2`

**output**

`1
7
occurrences = 2`

Comment: yes this is ok, but what i need to get input from user and i don't know how many element each array will contain!!!!

Comment: dosen't matter after taking input just put the values in differnt array and same code is good to go