# How to assert unordered HashSet elements in Java Unit Test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, hashset

I have a Unit Test for a service method that returns an `HashSet<T>` and I get it in the test method as shown below:

```
Set<EmployeeDTO> result = employeeService.findAllByUuid(uuid);
        
// I also convert the set to list for accessing by index:
List<EmployeeDTO> resultList = new ArrayList<>(result);
```

And try to assert as shown below:

```
assertEquals("Hans", resultList.get(0).getName());
```

However, there are 2 elements in the resultset and as expected, the order in the `HashSet` is changing. In this scene, how should I make assertions when I receive `HashSet` as return type of the tested method?

Comment: You can compare to predefined set https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355737/how-to-compare-two-hash-sets-in-java

Comment: @user7294900 Thanks for reply, but I need to compare by getting parameters inside Set. How can I do that?

Comment: Has anybody else have never needed to compare hashset values in unit test? Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

If the order can change, you can simply assert that the set contains the value, as the order changing means there is no reason why you should expect a specific value to occur at a specific index:

```
@Test
void testSetContainsHans(String uuid) {
  Set<EmployeeDTO> result = employeeService.findAllByUuid(uuid);
  boolean containsHans = false;
  for (EmployeeDTO emp : result) {
    if ("Hans".equals(emp.getName()) {
      containsHans = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  assertTrue(containsHans, "No employee named Hans was found.");
}
```

This test will pass if the set returned by `employeeService.findAllByUuid(uuid)` contains at least one `EmployeeDTO` with a name of "Hans", or fail with a message of `"No employee named Hans was found."` if it doesn't.