# Compare two Lists and same values store in third List issue

Tags: java, arraylist

Hy, I am having trouble with comparing two list. The goal is to compare two lists, find the same values and store those values into third list. What I have found till yet is just the way to return boolean value, but no way to return list value.. any ideas?

here are my two methods for getting values from database:

```
@Override
public List<BrojPolice> dohvatiBrojPolice() {
    List<BrojPolice> filter = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT*FROM ins2.kalk_cpi;",new Object[]{},
            (rs,rowNum) ->{
                BrojPolice bp = new BrojPolice();
                bp.setBroj(rs.getString("BROJ_POLICE"));
                return bp;
            });
    return filter;
}


@Override
public List<BrojPolice> dohvatiBrojPolice2() {
    List<BrojPolice> filter2 = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT*FROM ins_RAZNO.ADND_DATOTEKA;",new Object[]{},
            (rs,rowNum) ->{
                BrojPolice bp = new BrojPolice();
                bp.setBroj(rs.getString("BROJ_POLICE"));
                return bp;
            });
    return filter2;
}

public List<String> brojPolice(){
    boolean match = dohvatiBrojPolice().contains(dohvatiBrojPolice2());

     //ideas?

    return //List
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists this will help for u

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common elements in two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists)

Comment: the best way is to write an SQL query which returns exact result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`List.retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) as :

```
List<BrojPolice> common = new ArrayList<>(dohvatiBrojPolice());
common.retainAll(dohvatiBrojPolice2());
```

This would require the `BrojPolice` to be comparable with proper `hashCode` and `equals`.

If you're looking for a stream or forEach solution for this

```
List<BrojPolice> common = dohvatiBrojPolice().stream()
                                     .filter(a -> dohvatiBrojPolice2().contains(a))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Additionally to @nullpointer's answer, you should also implement an "equals" method for the BrojPolice class for your objects to be comparable

Comment: Is there any way to do it by using forEach?

Comment: @ZoranBajcer there is, I've updated the answer, but then given something can be completed using an inbuilt API, you shall stick to using it. **Aside**: your method should then also possibly have return type `List<BrojPolice>.`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of handling this in code you could write an SQL statement that gives the desired result

```sql
SELECT 
    BROJ_POLICE
FROM 
    ins2.kalk_cpi AS a
INNER JOIN 
    ins_RAZNO.ADND_DATOTEKA AS b
ON 
    a.BROJ_POLICE = b.BROJ_POLICE
```

That way you waste less memory on getting 2 possibly huge lists with only some common values.

```
// QUERY = query from above, omitted for readability
List<BrojPolice> list = jdbcTemplate.query(QUERY, new Object[0], 
    (rs,rowNum) -> {
            BrojPolice bp = new BrojPolice();
            bp.setBroj(rs.getString("BROJ_POLICE"));
            return bp;
    });
```

---

How to do it in java:

```
List<A> a = list1();
List<A> b = list2();
// A has to implement equals and hashCode
List<A> result = new ArrayList<A>();
for (A element : a) {
    if (b.contains(element)) // this requires a proper equals implementations
        result.add(element);
}

return result;
```

Note that doing `list1.contains(list2)` would always be `false` in this case because `contains` checks whether the element is contained.

Answer (score 1):

First your BrojPolice class needs to have hashCode and equals method implemented so that contains method works as expected. Try below method then:

```
public List<BrojPolice> intersection(List< BrojPolice > list1, List<BrojPolice> list2) {
    List<BrojPolice> intersection = new ArrayList<BrojPolice>();

    for (BrojPolice bp : list1) {
        if(list2.contains(bp)) {
            list.add(bp);
        }
    }

    return intersection;
}
```