# How to compare 2 arraylists and return repeating words

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Okay so i'm working with a code that is suppose to compare 2 seperate arraylists and return words that are repeating such as if input1 = "fun", "code" and input2 has "fun, java". The output should be fun but I am not sure how to approach this problem exactly

I've tried putting forloops together but they seem to be very innacurate and contain many errors with comparing array lists

```
    Scanner UI = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> input1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> input2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: How about using the built in function `retainAll`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common elements in two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the common elements from both arraylist and if you want to do `using for loop`, Iterate one of the array either `input1` or `input`

```
ArrayList<String> input1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> input2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Add all the elements that contained in `input2`, or you can simply follow `@Null` approach using `retainAll`

```
 for(String str : input1){

   if(input2.contains(str))){
     result.add(str);
     }
  }
```

**Using java-8**

```
List<String> result = input1.stream().filter(e->input2.contains(e))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Set<String> dupes = new HashSet<>();
search: for (String in : list1)
    for (String in2 : list2)
        if (in.equals(in2)) {
            dupes.add(in);
            continue search;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `retainAll` to get common elements of two *list*s:

```
    String str1 = "fun,prg,java";
    String str2 = "java,ide,fun,dev";
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(str1.split(","));
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(str2.split(","));
    List<String> commonElements = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    commonElements.retainAll(list2);
    System.out.println(commonElements);
```

Output:

```
[fun, java]
```