# Finding similar values between arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I want to put together a simple program that can take x amount of inputs, put them in an array, do the same thing again in a different array, and then check to see which inputs occur in both lists.

For obtaining the inputs, I can't think of a way for it to continue accepting any number of inputs and only stopping when the input says "stop" or "end" or something similar.

I'm a self-taught beginner, so pardon my ignorance when it comes to this stuff.

I haven't made the setup for the second array, but know how to do so (I'm fairly sure). I'm just stuck on the input issue and how to compare the inputs

```
//input of codes
    System.out.println("How many codes do you wanna put in?");
    x = input.nextInt();
    int[] binList = new int[x];
    System.out.println("Okay. Enter your codes:");
    for (int n = 0; n < x; n++) {
        binList[n] = input.nextInt();
    }

    //sort codes
    Arrays.sort(binList);

    //display codes
    System.out.println("Here are your codes:");
    for (int n = 0; n < x; n++) {
        System.out.println(binList[n]);
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using an array. If you used a dynamically sized collection such as `ArrayList` or `Vector`, you won't have any problems with resizing the array.

Comment: If you use a `List` then you can loop until you hit a magic number like -1

Comment: For comparing, first check if they are both the same size, and if so loop through checking element-by-element

Comment: Your second question sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists

Comment: This looks like a good fit for using a `Set` instead of an array - read the values into a a `Set`, then easy to check if the set contains something using the `contains()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For input taking part:**

> to continue accepting any number of inputs and only stopping when the input says "stop" or "end" or something similar

For your case, it is better to use `arraylist` in stead of `array` as you are taking input for `x` (unknown) number of items. Following program takes input from user until `-1` is entered:

```
ArrayList<Integer> binList = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Enter your codes:");
while (true) {
    x = input.nextInt();
    if (x == -1) break;
    binList.add(x);
}
```

**For comparison part:**

I assume that you have already created two arraylists, `binList` & `binList2`. I also assume that you have already taken input for variable number of items in both of the arraylists as stated above. Now for comparing them, use following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < binList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < binList2.size(); j++) {
        if(binList.get(i) == binList2.get(j)) {
            System.out.print(binList.get(i) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, the `size()` method returns the size of the arraylist. Here's the sample input and output for above codes:

> Sample input:

```
Enter your codes:

1 2 3 4 -1

Enter your codes:

2 4 5 7 9 -1
```

> Sample output:

```
2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // get first list elements
        List<Integer> list1 = getCodes(sc);
        // get second list elements
        List<Integer> list2 = getCodes(sc);

        sc.close();

        // display common codes
        System.out.println("Common elements are: ");
        list1.retainAll(list2);
        for (Integer code : list1) {
            System.out.println(code);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads input from console.
     * 
     * @param sc
     * @return
     */
    private static List<Integer> getCodes(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("How many codes do you wanna put in?");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Okay. Enter your codes:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any explanation of what you're doing differently from OP (and why) would greatly improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer showing how you could find similar array elements using `Set`. It starts with two `int` arrays, puts the values into two different `Set` collections, then walks through one set (doesn't matter which one – my example is walking through `setOne`) looking for items present in both sets, and finally keeping track of the matches in a new third set named `itemsInBothSets`.

```
int[] one = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] two = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

Set<Integer> setOne = new HashSet<>();
for (int i : one) {
    setOne.add(i);
}

Set<Integer> setTwo = new HashSet<>();
for (int i : two) {
    setTwo.add(i);
}

Set<Integer> itemsInBothSets = new HashSet<>();
for (Integer integer : setOne) {
    if (setTwo.contains(integer)) {
        itemsInBothSets.add(integer);
    }
}

System.out.println(itemsInBothSets.toString());
```

When I run this locally, this is the output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```